# Forcing liquibase to drop objects only if changelog was modified

Tags: java, liquibase

In our project we have a test server with our webapp which is redeployed on-demand. Now we have to stick with `dropFirst = true` because some of our changes modify init installation scripts (I know that it's not ordinary use case of liquibase, but it's fine for dev-test server). I want to force liquibase to drop objects ONLY if new schema was altered (eg, checksum failures will occur). Is it possible?

Comment: First, scripts committed must not be modified. But, if you want this scenario you could build your own script to execute a drop command in your database and then liquibase tasks would be executed. If you are using CI server create steps for that.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez how does it solve problem when I need this drop script to be executed only if there were any changes to changesets?

Comment: You will need to use Liquibase java classes to parse current changelog, calculate checksums etc and compare them with content in the database.